# Display uploaded files

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have uploaded files to the server using AsyncFileUpload. How can I display the existing files from the folder using asp.net web forms.? I would like to provide a link to the word document to open the file or save it. I couldn't find any example online. Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code:

Markup:

```
<asp:gridView runat="server" id="grid" >
<columns>
<asp:HyperLinkColumn DataTextField="Name" DataNavigateUrlField='<%#Eval(Server.MapPath("FullName")) %>' Target="_blank" />
</columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("YourDirectory"));
FileInfo [] files = dirInfo.GetFiles();
grid.DataSource=files;
grid.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to simply get the list of files in that directory using `Directory.GetFiles` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) and then display a suitable list using a gridview or repeater etc.